# Will webshells forever be a challenge for organizations?

Tags: attack-prevention, server, integrity, internet

The only ways of detecting webshells today are either by using FIM technologies, which are a problem if you start deploying them on "dirty" systems. You literally have to deploy them on clean systems in order to get a baseline of what a good state looks like.

Not only that, but the alternative to FIM technologies is using some signatures or some anomaly detecting systems, which won't always give you a solution (e.g if the attacker modified the code of an existing file as opposed to added his own webshell).

So, until some new technology is created, is this seriously where we stand?
The challenge is there, and attackers today still use webshells as one of their main weapons in the adversary arsenal.

Answer (score 5):

Webshells is an attack payload, not a vulnerability. If you don't have a vulnerability that allowed the attacker to install a webshell in the first place, then you don't really need to worry about webshells.

Webshell detectors may be useful to catch an attack that already happens. But if the attacker already manage to install a webshell, then the attacker are already in too deep for you to trust the machine.

Another use of webshell is for sysadmin using a webshell to administer their machines, these shells must be run over HTTPS and must be authenticated to prevent abuse by attackers. If an attacker manage to get into one of this legitimately installed webshells, then it's a vulnerability in the authentication mechanism surrounding the webshell, not due to the webshell itself.

Comment: "Webshells is an attack payload" - I would say that they can deliver attacks as payload but they are not payloads themselves. They are simply a file that allows some functionality and can facilitate further access into the network. Webshell detectors are the exact problem, solutions today are insufficient. And of course, if one has no vulnerabilities in their internet facing servers obviously there would be no webshells. That's a big if.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need advance anomaly or signature detection to detect the presence of unauthorized code on your servers. Typically speaking your webroot should be static after deployment which means you can generate an HMAC based on all the content of your webroot.

If you know you haven't changed any files on your webroot and you regnerate the HMAC with the same secret and get a different hash, then you know something has been modified.